# Do I need Push-Notification to remind the user of something

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, push-notification

I'm working on an app with `CoreData` which lets you type in items with a name and a date. Now I want the app to give the user a notification if the date of the item is, for example, in 5 days.

So an alert pops up and says: "Hey in 5 days is bla bla bla". So basicaly it's like the reminder app from Apple.

So the question is - do I need the `PushNotification` service to make this happen or is there another solution? I mean basically the whole app does not need any internet.

So what am I gonna do to make this feature? Do I need some kind of web server with a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [Local notification APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1). It works like the remote notification, but does not require internet and lets you schedule the notification event.
You'll find some sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely achieve this using Local Notifications. That way you will not need any internet connection at all. Here is a good tutorial:

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-scheduling-local-notifications-using-a-singleton-class/